# Scratches on wheel

Tags: wheels, paint-scratches, scratch, wheel-hub

I have a leased car for work and the wheel got scratched against the curb. Is there a way to get these scratches out of the wheel?
I am quite worried.

Thank you for your help!
Kaitlin
[image]

Comment: Yes, but it's not something you can do without specific tools and experience. Are you sure they weren't already scratched? Scratching the wheels is really easy to do. You might look into whether or not they care, and whether or not it's covered by insurance. If I were the company, I'd be more worried about the brakes.

Comment: There are places that specialize in repairing alloy wheels.